# Is there a simple way to blacklist any particular method/property in C# now?

Tags: c#, .net, lint, roslyn-code-analysis, editorconfig

My team members consistently use several methods incorrectly, unintentionally, and after leaving the same feedback too many times.. I would like to flag certain built-in methods/properties as at least warnings.

I use sonar cloud, so this would automatically block any PRs from passing the build when `Console.ForegroundColor`, as a bad example, is referenced at all. Then the developers would remember to use our own inhouse equivalent or reach out to a lead when there truly is an exception (there have been none after 100+ occurrences) in order to mark it as "OK" and allow the build to continue.

I do have an editorconfig that I've tuned to change the severity of some preexisting rules, but in this case I'm not sure that what I'm trying to do can be accomplished solely using this file and sonar.

Comment: You can create custom analyzers using Roslyn: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/tutorials/how-to-write-csharp-analyzer-code-fix

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BannedApiAnalyzers](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BannedApiAnalyzers) NuGet package to enforce an disallow-list of APIs that cannot be used. Coupled with [TreatWarningsAsErrors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/errors-warnings), you could fail the build if things you don't want used are introduced by people.

The documentation for the analyser can be found [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/blob/main/src/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BannedApiAnalyzers/BannedApiAnalyzers.Help.md).

For example, you could use a rule like this in `BannedSymbols.txt` to encourage use of NodaTime instead of `DateTime.Now`:

```
P:System.DateTime.Now; Use ISystemClock.GetCurrentInstant() from NodaTime instead.
```

Comment: How'd you guess one of my main use cases?  This is great. I think I can use this and then tweak the editorconfig so that it excludes this rule from test files which are the one location I don't really care about these things being used.  Thank you!